# Project works on codepen but not on IDE

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to reverse engineer an animation from [this codepen](https://codepen.io/aalainn/pen/mdBBEWy)

**my HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <canvas id="hero-lightpass"></canvas>  
</body>
</html>
```

**My CSS**

```
html {
height: 100vh;
}

body {
background: #000;
height: 500vh;
}

canvas {
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
max-height: 100vh;
max-width: 100vw;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h1 {
    color: white;
}
```

**My JS:**

```
// Canvas settings
    const canvas = document.getElementById("hero-lightpass");
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width=1158;
    canvas.height=770;

    
    // Preloading images to drastically improve performance
    const currentFrame = index => (`https://www.apple.com/105/media/us/airpods-pro/2019/1299e2f5_9206_4470_b28e_08307a42f19b/anim/sequence/large/01-hero-lightpass/${index.toString().padStart(4, '0')}.jpg`);
    const frameCount = 148; // There 148 images for that animation-sequence to load
    const images = [];

    const preloadImages = () => {
        for (let i = 1; i < frameCount; i++) {
            images[i] = new Image(); // This is functionally equivalent to document.createElement('img').
            images[i].src = currentFrame(i);
        }
    };

    preloadImages();


    // Draw the first image
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = currentFrame(1);
    img.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }


    // Scroll interactions
    const html = document.getElementsByTagName('html');
    
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {  
        const scrollTop = html[0].scrollTop;
        // console.log('scrollTop: ', scrollTop);
        // console.log('html.scrollHeight: ', html[0].scrollHeight);
        // console.log('window.innerHeight: ', window.innerHeight);
        const maxScrollTop = html[0].scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
        const scrollFraction = scrollTop / maxScrollTop;
        const frameIndex = Math.min(
            frameCount - 1,
            Math.floor(scrollFraction * frameCount)
        );
        // console.log('FrameIndex', frameIndex);

        requestAnimationFrame(() => context.drawImage(images[frameIndex + 1], 0, 0));

    });
```

but it doesn't work on my computer for some reason. It gives me the error message

"Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')
at  (/home/philocalyst/Desktop/test/script.js:3:32)"
**in my terminal and**

"Uncaught TypeError: canvas is null
 file:///home/philocalyst/Desktop/test/script.js:3"
**in my console**

the code is an exact copy of the codepen, but with the linking of the css and javascript. I can't figure out what I did wrong.

I tried linking the two together and reading the code and messages.

Comment: try moving the `script` declaration at the end of the `body` tag. alternatively, before running any of your javascript check [whether the document is ready](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState).

Comment: @BagusTesa I was about to say the same thing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: simply add `defer` attribute to your `<script>` and put this line _**inside**_ the `<head>` part (not in the body part)

Answer (score 1):

Like @BagusTesa said in the comments, the reason it is not working is clearly because the canvas selector in your script returns `null`.

This is because the DOM has not fully loaded yet and the script needs to wait until it's ready:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  // Code goes here
});
```

Or you need to put the script's source or code before the closing `<body>` tag:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="hero-lightpass"></canvas>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the new code, you can probably tell that the `<script>` tag is put **after** the canvas element so when the script runs, it knows that the canvas is there because it is run after that element has loaded.

Also refer to [this source (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction#accessing_the_dom)